# Filling in missing data Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a lot of missing data in between years and months of my dataframe that looks like:

```
    Year    Month   State        Value  
    1969    12        NJ         5500    
    1969    12        NY         6418     
    1970    8         IL         10093  
    1970    12        WI         6430      
    1970    7         NY         6140           
    1971    10        IL         10093          
    1971    6         MN         6850            
    1971    3         SC         7686          
    1972    12        FL         8772     
    2016    1         NJ         9000
```

For each state I need to fill out all the missing data from the beginning of the year the values began until 2018 but the only data that exists is mostly in between 1969 and 1990 so I just need to fill in the blanks.

The desired output (for NJ but needed for all states) would be:

```
Year    Month   State        Value  
1969    12        NJ         5500
1970    1         NJ         5500
1970    2         NJ         5500
1970    3         NJ         5500
1970    4         NJ         5500
1970    5         NJ         5500
1970    6         NJ         5500
.
.
1970    12        NJ         5500
.
.
2010    1         NJ         5500
2010    2         NJ         5500
2010    3         NJ         5500
.
.
2018    1         NJ         9000
```

I've tried turning the months into categorical values that range from 1-12 months, regroup and reset the index, and then use ffill to partition through the values into those newly made column indices like:

```
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], categories=range(1, 13))
df = df.groupby(['State', 'Year', 'Month']).first().reset_index()
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Region')['Value'].ffill()
```

But this method gives me NaN values like:

```
State   Year    Month   Value
NJ      1969    12      5500.0
NJ      1970    1       nan
NJ      1970    2       nan
NJ      1970    3       nan
.
.
NJ      2016    1       9000.0
```

I can't understand why this method has worked before as I've tested it on other data with actual results.

Comment: There is nowhere mentioned column `Region` in the Question though , where from its coming?

Comment: It was a category I built off each State that should not have been there.

Comment: Then how could reader know about that where and how you built that when thats not included into the question and later posting that into your own answer? doesn't seems to be off the track on the question itself? it all confusing and conflicting seeing the ques & answer.

Comment: I will change my question to include the 'Region' error and more information in my answer to clarify what the problem was as I cannot delete this question now. Hopefully this will be sufficient.

Comment: That will helpful for the SO readers & contributors and guys who are seeking same answers.

Comment: Changes made. Thank you, @pygo.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to all those who took time to correct this. It was a simple matter of accidentally grouping by a false column.

I had previously created a `'Region'` column based off a collection of the State variables which was called rather than the States themselves.

So to clarify:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Region')['Value'].ffill()
```

Needs to be changed into:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby('State')['Value'].ffill()
```

This method works correctly.